# Can I go back to USA if I entered at the age of 14 years old but overstaid my visa and left at 19 years old?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, overstaying

Here is my story. I went in California when I was 14 years old. I was with my family and I just learn that I overstayed... I had no idea, so I left the country at 19 years old... now its been over 6 years since I was there but i want to go this summer to see my brother and his son. I want to know if I would be forgiven because I was younger then 18 years old or I would be ban for 10 years? :/

Comment: You went to the US on what visa?

Comment: Do the authorities _know_ you overstayed?

Comment: @Malvolio: It doesn't really matter if they "know". When you apply for a visa or for an ESTA you are asked whether you have every violated the terms of your visa, and you have to answer truthfully or else it's fraud.

Comment: @user102008 -- I think we have different definition of the word "really".

Answer (score 5):

Under [Section 212(a)(9)(B) of the Immigration and Nationality Act](http://caracas.usembassy.gov/visas/section-212a9b-of-the-immigration-and-nationality-act.html), if you overstay in the US, you begin accruing "unlawful presence" after you turn 18 years old.

If you are unlawfully present for six months, you attract a 3 year ban, and if you are unlawfully present for a year, you attract a 10 year ban.

Based on the information you've given, it appears you remained in the US for more than 1 year after your 18th birthday, and therefore would be banned for 10 years.

It is possible to get a waiver from the ban in [only a very few circumstances](http://www.uscis.gov/i-601); you would need to be able to prove that you have a spouse, parent or child who is a US citizen or permanent resident and would suffer extreme hardship if you were not to return.

Comment: only hardship to spouse or parent qualify, not to child

Comment: Also, "overstay" is not a well-defined term. Only certain things trigger "unlawful presence" to start accruing. It is not clear from the description that they hit one of these things.